# Displaying dynamic text in Android

Tags: android

I'm creating a new activity in a BroadcastReceiver and am trying to figure out how to display dynamic text in the view.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
      String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

      SystemClock.sleep(1);
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, CallerIdActivity.class);
      myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
      context.startActivity(myIntent);
  }
}
```

How can I pass incomingNumber to the view displayed by the activity I just started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way that you got the number in the first place, by adding an extra to your Intent:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallerIdActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
  intent.putExtra("IncomingNumber", incomingNumber);
  context.startActivity(intent);
```

(You may want to change this Intent's name because you now have two Intents named `intent` which may cause trouble later.)

And check for this extra in `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("IncomingNumber");
    if(string != null) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: yuck, that's really gross. i can't believe android makes you serialize / deserialize everything to/from a string. what a pain. and you lose type info, etc. but does seem to be the only way i can see to do it :-p

Comment: I can only guess that `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is a String for aesthetic purposes (`800-555-1212`), I haven't used it myself. But you can pass any primitive data type, a few ArrayLists, and other already serialized data via [Intent's 25+ put extra methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putCharSequenceArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.CharSequence%3E%29). (So you not stuck converting everything to and from Strings.)